# How to generate data in a given format?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a matrix containing [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aiuy-dJpTpgfIK3xeS2sZCBo9Ig9lFIO/view?usp=sharing) points that I would like to plot and scale. Specifically, I want to generate a surface with random values on the order of 1 micrometer. I have attempted to plot it using the codes

```
       MatrixPlot[data] and ListDensityPlot[data],
```

but neither of them are working properly. Please provide guidance on how to plot and scale this data correctly.

Plot of generated data should looks like this type [image: generate data].

Comment: e.g., `data=RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]` This generates `10` random points with all values between `-1` and `+1`.  Try: `ListPlot3D[data]`.

Comment: Thank you, Syed. take a look at the data in the provided link. Could you please provide me with the code that can generate data points in that template?

Comment: This is not a one-click downloadable file  link, so I cannot.

Comment: Now, you can try to download it, for me, it is downloading in one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work from the image of your data. We need the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, and the values for $z$. We rearrange the data as $((x_1,y_1,z_{11}),(x_2,y_1,z_{21}),\ldots,(x_6,y_6,z_{66}))$.

```
x = Quantity[{-15.187, -15.068, -14.949, -14.831, -14.712, -14.593}, "Millimeters"];
y = Quantity[{15.119, 15., 14.881, 14.762, 14.643, 14.524}, "Millimeters"];
z = Quantity[{{-5.2487, -5.2483, -5.2479, -5.2473, -5.2457, -5.246},
  {-5.2477, -5.2473, -5.2459, -5.2453, -5.2456, -5.2449},
  {-5.2464, -5.246, -5.2455, -5.2449, -5.2442, -5.2435},
  {-5.2448, -5.2444, -5.2439, -5.2433, -5.2425, -5.2418},
  {-5.2431, -5.2425, -5.2421, -5.2414, -5.2407, -5.2399},
  {-5.2412, -5.2407, -5.2402, -5.2395, -5.2387, -5.2379}}, "Micrometers"];

dataxyz = Transpose[{Flatten[ConstantArray[x, Length@y]],
  Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[y, Length@x]]],
  Flatten[z]}];
```

Use `dataxyz` for three example plots.

```
g1 = ListPlot3D[dataxyz, AxesLabel -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> 12];
g2 = ListContourPlot[dataxyz, FrameLabel -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> 14];
g3 = ListDensityPlot[dataxyz, FrameLabel -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> 14];

GraphicsRow[{g1, g2, g3}, ImageSize -> 940]
```

[image: example images]

Comment: Thanks, @creidhne, It is working for me.  One more line code needs how to export dataxyz so that I can get the data format as shown in the attached picture.